# Kafka docker with SSL is not working (NiFi producer)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-nifi

I need to setup a single node kafka cluster with zookeper using docker-compose for some of my testing and need to enable SSL auth+encryption.

I tried to use different available docker images and achieve the same but could not succeed.

Below is the docker-compose :

```
version: "2"
services:
zookeeper:
image: "docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3"
hostname: zookeeper
container_name: zookeeper
tmpfs: "/datalog"
ports:
- "2181:2181"
volumes:
- "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
environment:
- ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
kafka-ssl:
image: "docker.io/bitnami/kafka:2-debian-10"
hostname: kafka-ssl
container_name: kafka-ssl
ports:
- "9092:9092"
- "9093:9093"
volumes:
- "kafka_data:/bitnami"
- './manual/kafka.server.keystore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks:ro'
- './manual/kafka.server.truststore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks:ro'

environment:
- KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
- ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
- KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
- KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://localhost:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
- KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SSL,SSL:SSL,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
- KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.keystore.jks
- KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS=o9pass
- KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS=o9pass
- KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.truststore.jks
- KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS=o9pass
- KAFKA_CFG_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM=
- KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_PROTOCOL=PLAINTEXT
- KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_PROTOCOL=PLAINTEXT
- KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SSL
- KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=CLIENT
- KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
- KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
depends_on:
- zookeeper
volumes:
zookeeper_data:
driver: local
kafka_data:
driver: local
```

Used Below commands to generate certificates :

```
keytool -keystore kafka.server.truststore.jks -alias ca-cert -import -file ca-cert
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias kafka -validity 3650 -genkey -keyalg RSA -ext SAN=dns:kafka-ssl
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias kafka -certreq -file ca-request-kafka
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in ca-request-kafka -out ca-signed-kafka -days 3650 -CAcreateserial
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias ca-cert -import -file ca-cert
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias kafka -import -file ca-signed-kafka
```

(Also tried with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools/master/kafka-generate-ssl.sh)

I am able to start kafka and ZK containers and able to produce message with plaintext (localhost:9092). But when I tried to produce with SSL (localhost:9093) I get below error on docker log :

Error on docker Log:

INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1001] Failed authentication with /172.19.0.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

I am using Apache Nifi to produce the message -

Publish Processor & SSLContext controller service screenshots are attached.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mahendra

Comment: Are you sure this is a Nifi issue? Are you able to get it working with `kafka-console-producer`?

Comment: I dont think it is Nifi issue....not really sure if I configured nifi correctly.
As I am using windows machine, could not really test with kafka-console-producer

Comment: Keep on getting "[SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1001] Failed authentication with /172.19.0.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)" error in docker compose console..so error is at kafka-ZK side only I think

Comment: And I am looking for SSL between kafka broker and producer and no auth/encryption req between Kafka-ZK.

Comment: Note - There are Windows binaries which allows you use console cli on Windows, they are inside the bin folder under windows